# Maximum and minimum inner product to orthogonal vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

Please excuse my usage of Dirac notations and less than informative question title. I have two normalized vectors $|i\rangle, |j\rangle$ and another one $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|i\rangle + |j\rangle)$ in a $N > 2$ dimensional inner product space.  A vector orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$ is some other vector (also normalized) $|\phi\rangle$. Among these vectors, I know the following inner products hold:

$$
\begin{align*}
\langle i | j \rangle &= 0, \\
\langle \phi | \psi \rangle &= 0, \\
\langle i | \psi \rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \\
\langle j | \psi \rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}. \\
\end{align*}
$$
Then, what can I say about the inner product of $|i\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$? I.e., what would be the expression to find the maximum and minimum value of the following inner products?

$$
\langle i | \phi \rangle, \\
\langle j | \phi \rangle.
$$
Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the  notation " |x⟩" meaning? Is it different that vector eg $\vec{x}$

Comment: It's the same, @partizanos .